# Does a prime ideal contains an irreducible element?

Tags: prime-factorization, maximal-and-prime-ideals, noetherian, unique-factorization-domains

**The context.** Let $R$ be an integral domain. It is known that a domain $R$ is a UFD if and only if any nonzero prime ideal contains a prime element.

It is also known that $R$ is a UFD if and only if any non zero element has a decomposition as a product of a unit and irreducible elements (which is automatic if $R$ is Noetherian, for example) and  any irreducible element is prime.

Thius, if $R$ is a Noetherian domain which is NOT a UFD, we known that there exists a nonzero prime ideal which does NOT contain a prime element.

The natural question coming into my mind is now:

**Question 1.** Let $R$ be a Noetherian integral domain which is not a field. Does any nonzero prime ideal of $R$ contains an irreducible element ?

**Question 2.** If answer to Q1 is NO, can we find sufficient conditions for which the answer to Q1 becomes YES ?

The answer is YES for $A[X]$ where $A$ is a PID (a full description of prime ideals are known, and they all contain an irreducible element)

I think I have proved it is also true for $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-d}], d>0$ squarefree  such that $d\not\equiv -1 \mod 4$ (I have not checked the details), but I have no clue how to prove it in general or how to find a counterexample (if there is any).

**Edit** In fact, Q1 is trivial. Any nonzero non unit $a\in \mathfrak{p}$ (prime ideal) maybe written as a product of irreducible elements. Since $\mathfrak{p}$ is prime, one of these irreducible elements belong to $\mathfrak{p}$.

So the real question is:

**Real question.** Let $R$ be an integral domain which has irreducible elements. Does any nonzero prime ideal contains an irreducible element ?

If there are counter examples, they are non noetherian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a$ be a nonzero element of your prime ideal $P$. If it's not irreducible, it
has a proper factorisation $a=a_1b_1$ where, one may assume that $a_1\in P$
and $b_1$ is not a unit. Again if $a_1$ is not irreducible, then
$a_1=a_2b_2$ where $a_2\in P$ and $b_2$ is not a unit.
If we keep going, we get a strictly increasing chain of principal ideals
$(a_1)\subset (a_2)\subset\cdots$ contradicting the Noetherian condition.

Comment: Thanks !  In fact, I came with a proof (which is more or less yours) . I leave my post anyway. The next question would be: can we find a non noetherian counterexample, provided that $R$ is supposed to have irreducible elements (to avoid counterexamples like the ring of all algebraic integers) ?

Comment: @GreginGre: You should just accept this answer and ask a followup question.

Comment: @GreginGre: Anyway, I think the answer is no. For instance, if $S$ is a valuation ring which is not DVR, then $R=S[x]$ is a domain and it has irreducibles (e.g. $x$ is irreducible) and for the maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$ in $S$, the ideal $\mathfrak m[x]$ is prime in $S[x]$ and has no irreducibles.